# How to invoke interface implementation using parametrized constructor and Factory class twice to run the tests in a class?

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, testng, factory

```
 //  Interface:

    public interface MailSettingConfiguration {

        @Before
        public void setMailServer() throws Exception;       

    }

    //Interface implementation1:

    public class MailSettingConfigurationImplementation1 implements MailSettingConfiguration {

        private static MailSettingsClient sacHelper;

        @Override
        public void setMailServer() throws JSONException
        {
            System.out.println("smtp configuration");
             sacHelper = new MailSettingsClient();

            sacHelper.setSmtpServer("servername", portnumber, "testname", "mailid", authentication, "", "", true);              
        }

    }

   // Interface implementation2:

    public class MailSettingConfigurationImplementation2 implements MailSettingConfiguration {

        private static MailSettingsClient sacHelper;

        @Override
        public void setMailServer() throws JSONException
        {
            System.out.println("smtp configuration");
             sacHelper = new MailSettingsClient();

            sacHelper.setSmtpServer("servername2", portnumber2, "testname2", "mailid2", authentication2, username, password, true);             
        }

    }        

   // Factory implementation:

    public class MailSettingClassFactory {

    @Factory
    public static Object[] createTestClassInstances() throws JSONException, IOException {
            return new Object[] {
        new TestClass1(
    new MailSettingConfigurationImplementation1()),new TestClass2(new MailSettingConfigurationImplementation2())
            };
        }        

  //  TestClass1 constructor 

     private MailSettingConfigurationImplementation1 mailSettingImpl1;
     private MailSettingConfigurationImplementation2 mailSettingImpl2;

    public TestClass1(MailSettingConfigurationImplementation1 mailSettingConfigurationImplementation1,MailSettingConfigurationImplementation2 mailSettingConfigurationImplementation2) throws JSONException, IOException {

            mailSettingImpl1.setMailServer();
            mailSettingImpl2.setMailServer();

        }

   // TestClass2 constructor         

    private MailSettingConfigurationImplementation1 mailSettingImpl1; 
    private MailSettingConfigurationImplementation2 mailSettingImpl2;

    public TestClass2(MailSettingConfigurationImplementation1 mailSettingConfigurationImplementation1, MailSettingConfigurationImplementation2 mailSettingConfigurationImplementation2) throws JSONException,IOException {
            mailSettingImpl1.setMailServer();
            mailSettingImpl2.setMailServer();
        }
```

How to run the Factory class with  @Factory annotation twice?

1. Initially run the Factory class with setmailserver() - server 1 implementation. setmailserver() is not parametrized.
2. Run all tests from 2 different classes Eg: TestClass1,TestClass2
3. Run the Factory class with setmailserver() - server 2 implementation. setmailserver() is not parametrized.
4. Run all tests from 2 different classes(same as step 2)
   Eg: TestClass1,TestClass2

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan can you please help me?

Comment: @NitishKshirsagar can you please help me?